# Updating MariaDB from MSSQL using Linked Server causes Error in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, mariadb

We are updating our onlineshop data using SSIS Packages to get data from MS SQL server 2016 to our mariadb database.
We set up a linked server connection using the latest mariadb odbc 3.1 64-Bit driver.

This works fine in most cases. But from time to time package executes fails on an error:

The rowset was using optimistic concurrency and the value of a column has been changed after the containing row was last fetched or resynchronized.

Searching stackoverflow and other resources many others seems to have solved their issues by configuring the odbc driver to

return matched row instead of affected rows

but this does not solve the problem in our case.

I have tried using the MYSQL ODBC Driver 8.0 but i cant configure port 3307 with is essential for me to get through the load balancer.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> The rowset was using optimistic concurrency and the value of a column has been changed after the containing row was last fetched or resynchronized.

This is always a risk with optimistic concurrency (row versioning in SQL Server).  In a way, it's not unlike a deadlock error with pessimistic concurrency (transactional isolation).  In both scenarios, you need to have a plan (and code) in place to handle the issue.

This is partly a business question and partly a tech question.  From the business side, what is the desired outcome in this case?  Which update should "win"? You need to know this before doing anything else. From the tech side, setting up a retry loop with some small wait between tries should do it.

If you are hitting this problem a lot, you might consider using  transactional isolation instead.

Comment: That's what I am not sure. I don't really know how linked server and odbc is dealing with that row versioning thing of mssql server.

So using the mysql odbc driver completely kills this problem by checking the box "return matched row instead of affected rows" in the ODBC settings. So I am not really sure why this is not the same behavior with the mariaDB ODBC driver.